# Can antibiotic resistance cause problems for the microorganisms producing them?

Tags: evolution, microbiology, bacteriology, mycology, antibiotics

My understanding is that antibiotics are naturally produced by microorganisms as a defensive measure against certain kinds of bacteria. For example, some Penicillium molds produce penicillin.

Clearly, antibiotic resistance has direct negative effects for humans because it makes certain infections more difficult to treat. But could this resistance also lead to problems for the microorganisms that produce antibiotics in the first place?

If this were the case then could there be additional negative "second order" effects for humans?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Will all bacteria become resistant against all antibiotics in the long term?](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/90115/will-all-bacteria-become-resistant-against-all-antibiotics-in-the-long-term) Specifically, see the first paragraph of my answer.

Comment: I depends on what you mean by "problems." Antibiotic resistance mechanisms have probably existed in the wild for nearly as long as naturally occurring antibiotics. It's certainly possible for an antibiotic resistant organism to have an antagonistic effect on an antibiotic-producing organism, for example by competing for key nutrients or niche space. It's also possible for positive interactions to occur where one or both organisms benefits from symbiosis with the other.  Also not sure what kinds of second order effects for humans you have in mind.